# Get path to assets file in iOS: NSBundle is missing

Tags: ios, nsbundle

I am trying to get the *path* to a file I have in the `Assets.xcassets` directory for my iOS app, but I am not able to. It seems like I should use `NSBundle.mainBundle()` somehow, but Xcode cannot find `NSBundle` *even though I import Foundation or UIKit*. If I do auto completion on "NSBundle" I get the following options:

```
NSBundleErrorMaximum
NSBundleErrorMinimum
NSBundleResourceRequest
NSBundleExecutableArchitecturePPC
NSBundleExecutableArchitectureI386
NSBundleExecutableArchitecturePPC64
NSBundleExecutableArchitectureX86_64
NSBundleOnDemandResourceInvalidTagError
```

I have no clue what these are for. So my questions are:

1. How can I import `NSBundle` into my project?
2. How can I get the path to the following file: `Assets.xcassets/Database.dataset/database.txt`?

Note that I am able to get the *contents* of the file doing the following, but I want the *path* to the file.

```
fileprivate static func readDatabaseFileFromAssets() -> NSDictionary
{
    let databaseAsset = NSDataAsset(name: "Database", bundle: Bundle.main)
    let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: databaseAsset!.data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments)
    return json as! NSDictionary
}
```

Comment: `NSBundle` is now just `Bundle`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many things have changed names in Swift3!

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Database", withExtension: "txt")
// url.path
```